# $F(f)\subset F(x)$ is an algebraic extension of degree $\max(p,q)$ if $f$ is non constant quotient polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field, with $f=a/b\in F(x)$ the quotient of coprime polynomials $a,b\in F[x]$ of degree $p$ and $q$ respectively.

> How do I prove that if $f$ is not constant, then $F(f)\subset F(x)$ is an algebraic extension of degree $\max(p,q)$?

I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem, maybe someone can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205227/minimal-polynomial-of-x-over-k-left-fracpxqx-right-subset-kx.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = t$. Then you can think of your extension as $F(t) \subset F(t)[x]/(a(x)-tb(x))$. I can elaborate more but you should try finishing the proof from here on.

Comment: Thank you, I will let you know how it goes

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't able to continue. Would you mind completing your answer?

Comment: What is the degree of the polynomial $a(X)-tb(X)$ as a polynomial with coefficients in $F(t)$?

Comment: Try proving that a - tb is irreducible, it will help to use gauss lemma at some point

Comment: What does it mean if a - tb is irreducible?