# Minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K(x^n)$ where $x$ is transcendental

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, transcendental-numbers

I am struggling with the following problem:

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension and $x \in L$ be transcendental. Show that the field extension $K(x^n) \subset K(x)$ is algebraic of degree $n$. Determine the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K(x^n)$

So, it is pretty obvious that the degree cannot be larger than $n$ since we have the polynomial
$$p(t)=t^n-x^n$$
which has $x$ as a root. And now it would either be sufficient to show that $p$ is irreducible or that the degree is greater or equal than $n$. I have tried both but the crucial point is that I do not really know how the elements in $K(x^n)$ look like since it is not an algebraic extension where we know the basis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimal polynomial of $x$ over $ K\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right) \subset K(x) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205227/minimal-polynomial-of-x-over-k-left-fracpxqx-right-subset-kx)

Comment: @AnneBauval I am not quite sure this answers my question. My polynomial is not linear over $K(x^n)[t]$.

Comment: If $K$ happens to have a primitive $n$th root of unity $\zeta$, then $x\mapsto \zeta x$ induces an automorphism of $K(x)$ that is the identity on $K(x^n)$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But it is not given that $K$ contains a primitive $n$-th root.

Comment: @FlynnFehre The point of the argument there is that by Gauss's lemma it suffices to show the polynomial is irreducible over $K[x^n][t]=K[t][x^n]$ and then you can use the fact that it is linear in the variable $x^n$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Alright I get it. Although I haven't come across Gauss's lemma yet. So I might have to prove that first. Do you think there might be a more elementary way?

Comment: @FlynnFehre I am absolutely sure that *[the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205227) answers your question.* What is called $t$ over there is the rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ which in your case is simply $\frac{x^n}1.$ And it is proved that the polynomial $P(X)-tQ(X)=X^n-t=X^n-x^n$ is the minimal polynomal of $x$ over $K(t)=K(x^n).$

Comment: For a more elementary approach, you could just explicitly show that $1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $K(x^n)$.  Just write down a general linear combination of them and clear denominators, and notice that no cancellation can happen between the terms because their exponents are all different mod $n$.

Comment: @EricWofsey One more thing: I have looked up every Gauss's lemma here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_Lemma  However, if I am not mistaken, there is not the statement from the duplicate, is there? It seems these are statements primarily for $\mathbb{Q}$. Or can they be generalized for any field?

Comment: @FlynnFehre: It is more generally a statement about polynomials over the fraction field of a UFD.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)#Statements_for_unique_factorization_domains.